# How to display alert message on a standard SF page on click of standard "save" button

Tags: apex, administration

Hi I want to display an alert box onclick of a standard save button on a standard SF page. When the user select a product(say pqr), and press save ,he should be prompted that he should select a newer version(say xyz).

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do this is via a validation rule. Create a validation rule on the object you are saving that checks if an old product is selected. If so, display an error.

There are some alternatives like overriding the 'save' button with a javascript button, or overriding the complete page with VisualForce, but I wouldn't go there if validation rules work for you. An elaborate example can be found here: http://www.valnavjo.com/blog/modal-dialog-on-a-standard-salesforce-page/

Comment: Hi guy, Thanks for the reply.Yes validation would work but I want an alert box on the same "save" button to show a pop up message which asks if you are sure to add the product 'pqr'(old one). If he clicks OK ,then continue and add the old product and if cancel he can add the new product by selecting 'xyz'.

Comment: OK, you might want to update your question with that as it is quite relevant :-) I'll update my answer accordingly (all to make this discussion reusable in the future for others with the same question)